# android - itemizedoverlay update marker on mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-overlay

I've some ItemizedOverlay adding onto MapView. I'm able to show case the static marker which is been initialized initially. Now say after 5 markers, I need to update the marker of the first or second one precisely, how can I do it? I want to refresh or update the previous markers which is already visible, how to achieve this?

```
 public class MyItemOverlay extends ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> {

        public MyItemOverlay(ArrayList<OverlayItem> pList,Drawable marker, ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem> pOnItemGestureListener, ResourceProxy pResourceProxy) {
            super(pList, marker, pOnItemGestureListener, pResourceProxy);
}}
```

Comment: You will need to hold references to the markers that you add to either your map or your overlay.

Comment: and how do I do that? @JamieB

Comment: You would add each ItemOverlay / Marker to an ArrayList and refer back to the array when you need to modify the marker.

Comment: I'm currently using a ArrayList of OverlayItem, If I refer back I get only OverlayItem. How would I set the marker to that particular overlayitem which is there?

Comment: OverlayItem holds references to markers though? Or even if OverlayItem only holds references to a single marker, you could hold a collection of OverlayItem.

Comment: Yes, Got it! Thanks. BTW @JamieB do you know how to load Maptiles off the UI thread? Because I keep getting `05-14 16:05:17.967: I/Choreographer(12806): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.05-14 16:05:16.115: D/dalvikvm(12806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 47K, 4% free 168590K/174276K, paused 635ms, total 636ms`
What do you suggest?

Comment: MapView shouldn't trigger Choreographer issues - are you sure it is the mapview causing it and not other logic?

Comment: Yes, I'm using cutom MapTileSource using osmdroid, unfortunately I keep geeting this messages on and on again.

Comment: Would be interesting to see if you could add the tile loading to an ASyncTask and have the UI update on the postExecute.

Comment: I tried that AsyncTask the bitmap doesn't draw, its empty. And there are tons of bitmap maptiles, would it be fine to execute parallel using AsycTask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should hold a list of either Markers related to the MapView in the current context or hold references to the OverlayItem (which may contain marker(s)) inside. This will allow you to access the markers by reference at any point.